# Visual Studio published application install/update timeout problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publishing

we are developing a Winform application in C# and Visual Studio 2010 which we publish to a folder on our server. We use the 'installation folder URL' field in the publish tab with 'http://server/folder'. The problem is that if more than one person trying to install or update the application on their machine, the install or update will fail and the error log says it is has timed out, I have added the contents of the log file to the end of this post.

It seems like a some kind of locking is going on, the folder we publish to on the server has read only permission. We have tried many things, like using 'Clean Solution' and 'Rebuild Solution'.

Does anyone know about this problem or have any suggestions that might help. Thank you for you help.

Jing Jing Tao

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO
>       Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
>       Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.225
>       System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>       clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.225 (RTMGDR.030319-2200)
>       dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>       dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)
>
> SOURCES
>     Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming
>   /Microsoft/Windows/Start%20Menu/Programs/TiffinSolutions/Removal%20Software.appref-ms%7C
>                           Server      : Microsoft-IIS/7.0
>                           X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
>       Deployment Provider url     : £http://tiffinsolutions.zapto.org/ApplicationUpdateFiles/Removal%20Software.application
>
> ERROR SUMMARY
>       Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>       * Activation of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TiffinSolutions\Removal Software.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>           + Downloading £http://tiffinsolutions.zapto.org/ApplicationUpdateFiles/Application Files/Removal Software_1_1_0_157/Removal Software.exe.manifest did not succeed.
>           + The operation has timed out
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
>       No transaction error was detected.
>
> WARNINGS
>       There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
>       * [24/05/2011 14:22:16] : Activation of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TiffinSolutions\Removal Software.appref-ms| has started.
>       * [24/05/2011 14:22:16] : Performing necessary update check as specified by the deployment.
>       * [24/05/2011 14:22:17] : Consuming new update.
>       * [24/05/2011 14:22:17] : Installation of the application has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS
>       Following errors were detected during this operation.
>       * [24/05/2011 14:23:57] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
>           - Downloading http://tiffinsolutions.zapto.org/ApplicationUpdateFiles/Application Files/Removal Software_1_1_0_157/Removal Software.exe.manifest did not succeed.
>           - Source: System.Deployment
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>               at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ConsumeUpdatedDeployment(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentUpdate(SubscriptionState& subState, String& errorPageUrl)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String& errorPageUrl, TempFile& deployFile)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
>           --- Inner Exception ---
>           System.Net.WebException
>           - The operation has timed out
>           - Source: System
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>               at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
>       No transaction information is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the conclusion we were able to gain was that the server is not setup for hosting and we used our hosted service to store our files.